# Runtime Environment Variables in React for UAT and Live for a single build devops

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-devops, environment-variables

Sorry if you think this has been asked before but there doesn't seem like a good solution anywhere.

I have a build pipeline that packages up my react app into a single artifact.
The release pipeline pushes that artifact to different Azure storage accounts for each environment (Dev, UAT, Live).

Surely there is a way to use DevOps variables to configure variables in my package per environment.

Other solutions:

1. One build per environment - I don't want to do this because I would need to create a branch for each environment, a pipeline for each, the env configs for each, and a release pipeline for each. This means a change to 1 environment takes 3 times as long. Also, the time to build these environments trebles.
2. Using a JSON file and swapping this out on deployment. - This didn't work because webpack imported the JSON file into the build so whilst I transformed the `config.json` files. It was too late. This seems similar to using `env.development` and `env.live` and would mean 3 builds
3. Pull environment out of the request URL and call an endpoint - seems like my only option but definitely has flaws.

This isn't an issue in .NET (or Java I believe, .NET is my background) and was solved years ago with web.config and appSettings.

Please let me know if you have solved this and how?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Runtime Environment Variables in React for UAT and Live for a single build devops

We could use the task [Replace Tokens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) to use DevOps variables to configure variables in the package per environment:

[image]

The format of variable in `.json` file is `#{TestVar}#`.

And define the key's values on the Variables based on the stages:

[image]

Comment: So we got it working by doing this, although you have to make the json file not compile into the bundle. We put it in the public folder and on load of the app, make a Get request to retrieve the files. Thanks for your help